# How to move through a xml file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<root>
    <weapon>
        <name>Basic Laser</name>
        <epc>1</epc>
        <dpc>1</dpc>
        <rm>1</rm>
        <gl>10</gl>
        <upgCost>1.5</upgCost>
        <autoDps>0</autoDps>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <upg>
            <name>Blue cell</name>
            <bought>0</bought>
            <units>25</units>
            <cost>1000</cost>
            <change>
                <type>0</type>
                <num>2</num>
            </change>
        </upg>
    </weapon>
    <shield>
        ...
    </shield>
    <weapon>
        ...
    </weapon>
</root>
```

This is the structure of my XML i cant seem to figure out how to move through it in the way i want. Essentialy i want to move through root first searching for weapon,shield tags and only for children of root not grandchildren of root etc.

After that i want to save weapons in a variable and access its stats etc. I have been trying varius ways but nothing gives me this result of limiting where and for what i want to serach.

```
root = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
weapons = root.getElementsByTagName("weapon");
weapons[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

I though that this should work but it doesnt i get no real data returned. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: it is better to use jquery api to parse the xml

Comment: @theinvisible What's the advantage?

Comment: can you give me a example?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `getElementsByTagName` on a `NodeList`.

```
root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
weapons = root.getElementsByTagName("weapon");
weapons[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
```

Comment: how do i access the values of <name>, <epc> etc of each weapon now?

Comment: @Vajura What you were doing should work just fine if your document was parsed correctly.

Comment: @Vajura Well, what's the value of `weapons.length`? Also, use `textContent` instead of `nodeValue` since you are trying to get the content of an element node.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line: `root = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;`. `xmlDoc.documentElement` is the `root` element. You're then getting its `childNodes`, which is a `NodeList`, not an element. It therefore doesn't have a `getElementsByTagName` method.

You get meaningful data if you select the `root` node and then do `getElementsByTagName` on that:

```
root = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
weapons = root.getElementsByTagName("weapon");
```

You then get a list of `weapon` elements.

But this probably isn't the best way. If I were you, I would use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var weapons = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('root > weapon');
```

Or to get the `name` elements:

```
var weaponNames = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('root > weapon > name');
```

You would then have to loop through each element to get its value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < weaponNames.length; i++) {
    console.log(weaponNames[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
    // or
    console.log(weaponNames[i].innerHTML);
}
```

You should note that `nodeValue` returns `null` if used on an element node. You need to get the text nodes instead, which is why you need `firstChild.nodeValue`.